# Got error while posting comment

Tags: 7, comments, wsod

I'm using **"Unpublish comments with keywords"** action. I've just noticed a PHP error on submitting any comment.

> drupal_render() expects an array but comment_unpublish_by_keyword_action() calls it with $comment object. And we have a WSOD.

That's part of error.log

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /.../includes/common.inc on line 5672, referer: `http://.../comment/reply/28`

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know why/when drupal render is called in the first place ? Unpublishing a comment and rendering it seem quite different actions - I don't understand how they can be called on the same object.

Comment: answer refer to drupal.org http://drupal.org/node/1461732

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's already in the issue que at drupal.org (a better place to resolve module issues then here)

Although doesn't look the patch has been merged into the latest cut release (as of time of writing this), but you can see the changes that were made here:

http://drupal.org/node/1461732#comment-5727124